# Image does not horizontally line up with the text above and below it with 960 grid

Tags: css, 960.gs

Any idea why my image does not horizontally line up with the text above and below it please?
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2306276/site/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a different class for the image element than for the text elements you want on the right column. Set the image's class to grid_13 (same as the text) and add push_3, so it moves 3 columns to the right.
It'd be better to rearrange your elements into divs though; otherwise you'll have to give each element specific properties, and that beats the purpose of using a grid system.

Comment: great, that worked! thanks. Only problem my image is now huge!

Comment: fixed by adding a div container.

Comment: Yeah, like I said, it's better to place your elements in divs and give the divs the grid_X, push_X classes, otherwise you'll have to give each element specific properties to style them. I'd put a <div> with class grid_3, and another <div> with class grid_13 inside each status div, and the individual elements inside those instead.

Answer (score 0):

In the 960 Grid system, every nested class has to have a "grid_x".  You div's in between ("Status" etc) which don't use the grid system, I imagine these are throwing it off.

Try adding grid classes to these, using "alpha" and "omega" where appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, added "alpha" where appropriate, no change at all.